# Access int from Another Objective-C Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, int

I've trying to get an int from another class and it just says that the number is 0 (but it's not).

This is in Class2.h:

```
@interface Class2 : SKScene <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>{
    Class1 * class;
}
```

This is in Class2.m:

```
NSLog(@"%i", class.thisint);
```

This is in Class1.h:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) int thisint;
```

This is in Class1.m (in viewDidLoad):

```
thisint = 5;
```

The NSLog is being called well after the viewDidLoad method but it just keeps saying 0. How do I get this int from Class1? I don't know if the fact that Class2 is an SKScene affects this...

Comment: try using the accessor to assign thisint? self.thisint = 5; I would also remove (assign, nonatomic) for primitives and just declare the property like @property int thisint; Also, where are you alloc and init-ing the ivar named 'class' in Class2 ? All you have thus far is a nil pointer to Class1 named 'class'

Answer (score 1):

`class` is an existing method on NSObject and I would hope that you've just used that name for the purposes of this question - if not, please change the name of the variable, it will only lead to confusion.

What do you see if you log `class`:

```
NSLog(@"%@",class);
```

(Put that next to where your existing log is)

How and where are you assigning to the `class` variable?

A value of 0 probably means one of two things:

- `class` is `nil`. This means you haven't assigned it anywhere. You don't magically get a value in a property just because you've declared one
- `class` is a different instance to the one you think it is. This is a common beginner mistake, where you've done something like

  ```
  class = [[Class2 alloc] init];
  ```

Which creates a *new* instance. You need to get a reference to the existing instance, which I can't tell you how to do without seeing more code.

Comment: Yeah I used class just for the example. The original was game. When I do NSLog(@"%@",class); it says (null). This is the only Class1 code I have in Class2 (in the .h): Class1 * class;

I didn't make a new instance because I knew it wouldn't work and I basically need to know to to make a reference to it.

Comment: Well you either need an outlet, if you're using IB, or wherever you create the thing you need to pass it along. Like I said, it's hard to tell without more details.